# how to loop a matrix let the number on the diagonal has high priority?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I am working on a project which need to find a certain number in a two dimensional array(a matrix) .the visiting order of matrix order is like this (4*4 matrix). Now I stand in the position 0. Equivalently, I want to visit the matrix element in diagonal firstly.

```
0  2  7  14
3  1  5  12
8  6  4  10
15 13 11 9
```

Besides, how to break two nest loop in c++ while do not use goto statement.

Comment: what your understanding saying to do..means want to use 2 for loops for traversing

Comment: Until now, I have to visit the matrix element row by row. The matrix has a small size, but the visiting operation will execute many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will traverse a square matrix of any size, with priority on the diagonal

```
#define SIZE 4

static int test[SIZE][SIZE] =
{
    {   0,    2,    7,    14  },
    {   3,    1,    5,    12  },
    {   8,    6,    4,    10  },
    {  15,   13,   11,     9  }
};

int main( void )
{
   int diagonal, delta;

   for ( diagonal = 0; diagonal < SIZE; diagonal++ )
   {
       cout << test[diagonal][diagonal] << endl;

       for ( delta = 1; delta <= diagonal; delta++ )
       {
           cout << test[diagonal-delta][diagonal] << endl;
           cout << test[diagonal][diagonal-delta] << endl;
       }
   }
}
```

Here's one way to break out of a nested loop without a goto

```
done = false;
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
    {
        if ( some_condition_is_met )
        {
            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( done )
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use another array with array indices (since the size of your array is probably constant anyway), for instance, if you stored first array in one dimensional c++ array, then

```
int actual_arr[16];
int indices[16] = {0, 5, 1, 4, 10, 6, 9, 2, 8, 15, 11, 14, 7, 13, 3, 12 };
```

So then you can write a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i  < 16; ++i)
{
  actual_arr[indices[i]]++;
}
```

So every field in indices is an index of actual_arr which will be visited at this point.
You can do it with two dimensional representation, too, if it required. Just replace `int indices[16]` with `std::pair<int, int> indices[16]` and you're good to go.

Especially when you have a fixed-size array and visit it many times, this is good solution, since it doesn't involve any computation in the loop.

Btw. As a sidenote, mathematically speaking, the indices array would be called a permutation and can be an operation in [permutations group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group).

Answer (score 1):

To move to the element on the right, you increment a row.
To move to the element on the left, you decrement a row.
To move to the element below, you increment a column.
To move to the element above, you decrement the column.
Now to move diagonally, observe how the row and columns change and apply a combination of the above.